# What limitations does WPF have comparing to XNA?

Tags: .net, wpf, xna

I believe WPF is better for game in situations like creating buttons, textblock, label, progressbar...

Comment: This is all contingent on what you are defining a "game" as...

Comment: What game are you creating that needs buttons and a progressbar?  It might help if you defined your requirements better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF is a very different technological approach to graphics from XNA.

First off, it's a retained mode API instead of an immediate mode API.  This will give you less (almost no) control over how and when things are rendered when compared to XNA.  It also potentially will have a higher cost in terms of performance and potentially lower responsiveness, at least with a lot of objects (when compared to a properly implemented XNA game).

That being said, WPF is much simpler to implement, especially for 2D graphics.  WPF 3D can be simple, but awkward to use at times.  It is much easier to handle the user interface in WPF when compared to XNA, however.

XNA also has the benefit of being cross platform (ie: Windows desktops, phone, and XBOX).